# Simple IRC bot with plugin support

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes, plugin

I'm looking to see if there is anything in this I could have done better or see if could have structured the code better.  [Here is the project on GitHub](https://github.com/desg/desgb0t).

```
import socket
import string
import sys
import os

path = "plugins/"
plugins = []
# Load plugins
sys.path.insert(0, path)
for f in os.listdir(path):
    fname, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if ext == '.py':
        mod = __import__(fname)
        plugins.append(getattr(mod, fname))
sys.path.pop(0)

class IRC_Client(object):

    """docstring for IRC_Client"""
    sock = ""

    def __init__(self, ircserver, ircnicklist, ircident, ircrealname,
                 ircchanlist, nickpassword=None, ircport=6667):
        super(IRC_Client, self).__init__()
        if not isinstance(ircnicklist, list):
            raise TypeError("nicklist is not an instance of list")
        elif not isinstance(ircchanlist, list):
            raise TypeError("chanlist is not an instance of list")

        self.ircnicklist = ircnicklist
        self.ircident = ircident
        self.ircrealname = ircrealname
        self.ircchanlist = ircchanlist
        self.ircserver = ircserver
        self.ircport = ircport
        self.nickpassword = nickpassword

    def createconnection(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((self.ircserver, self.ircport))

    def sendmessage(self, sender, message):
        sent = "PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (sender, message)
        self.sock.send(sent)

    def sendpong(self, sender):
        sent = "PONG %s\r\n" % sender
        self.sock.send(sent)

    def sendnotice(self, sender, message):
        sent = "NOTICE %s :%s\r\n" % (sender, message)
        self.sock.send(sent)

    def sendctcp(self):
        pass

    def setnick(self, nick):
        self.sock.send("NICK %s\r\n" % nick)

    def joinchannel(self, channel):
        self.sock.send("JOIN %s\r\n" % channel)

    def getusernick(self, serverbuffer):
        usernick = serverbuffer[0].split("!")
        usernick = usernick[0].replace(":", "")
        return usernick

    def getusermessage(self, serverbuffer):
        message = ""
        if len(serverbuffer) >= 4:
            serverbuffer[3] == serverbuffer[3][1:]
            for i in range(3, len(serverbuffer)):
                message += serverbuffer[i] + " "
            return message

    def getchannel(self, serverbuffer):
        if len(serverbuffer):
            return serverbuffer[2]

    def serverreplies(self, serverbuffer):
        serverbuffer = string.split(string.rstrip(serverbuffer))

        if serverbuffer[0].lower() == 'ping':
            self.sendpong(serverbuffer[0])
        if serverbuffer[1] == "431":
            print "No nick was given"
            exit()
        if serverbuffer[1] == "432":
            print "Erroneus nick"
            exit()
        if serverbuffer[1] == "433":
            if len(self.ircnicklist) != 0:
                self.setnick(self.ircnicklist.pop())
            else:
                raise IndexError("All nicks from nicklist are in use")

            for channel in self.ircchanlist:
                self.joinchannel(channel)

    def commandparser(self, line):
        line = string.split(string.rstrip(line.lower()))
        if (len(line) >= 4 and line[1] == 'privmsg'):
            map(lambda command: command(self, line), plugins)


    def connect(self):
        self.createconnection()
        self.setnick(self.ircnicklist[0])
        self.sock.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n"
                       % (self.ircident, self.ircserver, self.ircrealname))

        if not self.nickpassword:
            pass
        else:
            self.sock.send("PASS %s\r\n" % self.nickpassword)

        for channel in self.ircchanlist:
            self.joinchannel(channel)

    def loop(self):

        readbuffer = ""
        while 1:
            readbuffer = self.sock.recv(1024)
            temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
            readbuffer = temp.pop()
            for line in temp:
                print line
                self.serverreplies(line)
                self.commandparser(line)
                logger(self, line)

    def runclient(self):

        self.connect()
        self.loop()


def logger(ircclientinstance, serverbuffer):

    serverbuffer = string.split(string.rstrip(serverbuffer))

    if serverbuffer[1].lower() == "privmsg":
        if serverbuffer[2] in ircclientinstance.ircchanlist:
            filename = ("%s.log" % serverbuffer[2])
            f = open(filename, 'a+')
            f.write("<%s>%s\n" % (ircclientinstance.getusernick(
                serverbuffer), ircclientinstance.getusermessage(serverbuffer)))
            f.close()
        else:
            filename = ("%s.log" % ircclientinstance.getusernick(serverbuffer))
            f = open(filename, 'a+')
            f.write("<%s>%s\n" % (ircclientinstance.getusernick(
                serverbuffer), ircclientinstance.getusermessage(serverbuffer)))
            f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # TODO: config file? maybe
    mybot = IRC_Client('irc.freenode.net', ['swaglorde', 'swaglordeh'], 'swaglorde', 
                    'swaglorde', ['#dtest'])
    mybot.runclient()
```

Example of a plugin:

I am thinking about converting my plugin system to a class based system.  I am also not sure if it would better, but I do have a bit of code I am reusing with every plugin.

```
import requests


def showInfo(tvname):
    tvname = tvname.replace(' ', '+')
    tvinfo = requests.get(
        "http://services.tvrage.com/tools/quickinfo.php?show=" + tvname).text
    try:
        tvdata = tvinfo.split('\n')
        tvinfo = []
        for data in tvdata:
            data = data.split('@')
            tvinfo.append(data)

        return tvinfo
    except:
        return None


def next(ircclientinstance, serverbuffer):
    commandname = 'next'
    commands = {':!': True, ':.': False, ':@': True}

    # This needs to be included in all plugins that take arguements
    commandarguements = ""
    parseargs = serverbuffer[3:][1:]

    for x in parseargs:
        commandarguements += x.strip() + " "

    if commandarguements == '':
        output = "No info found :3"
    else:
        try:
            tvinfo = showInfo(commandarguements)
            output = "[%s] :: [Next: %s] [Airs: %s]" % (
                tvinfo[1][1], tvinfo[7][1].replace('^', ' '), tvinfo[15][1])
        except:
            output = "No info found :3"

    # this needs to be included with all plugins
    if serverbuffer[3][2:] == commandname:
        if serverbuffer[3][:2] in commands:
            notice = commands.get(serverbuffer[3][:2])

            if not notice:
                if serverbuffer[1] == "privmsg":
                    if serverbuffer[2] in ircclientinstance.ircchanlist:
                        ircclientinstance.sendmessage(serverbuffer[2], output)
                    else:
                        ircclientinstance.sendmessage(
                            ircclientinstance.getusernick(serverbuffer), output)
            else:
                ircclientinstance.sendnotice(
                    ircclientinstance.getusernick(serverbuffer), output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments regarding the main code:

- Try to order imports alphabetically
- Use underscores to separate words in method names (`createconnection` -> `create_connection`, `sendmessage`, `send_message`, etc.)
- Use class attributes instead of hardcded constants (`"431"` -> `self.ERR_NONICKNAMEGIVEN`, `"432"` -> `self.ERR_ERRONEUSNICKNAME`, etc.)
- Use `if`/`elif`/`elif` instead of `if`/`if`/`if` to avoid unnecessary checks
- Use the `logging` module instead of `print` statements.
- To check if a list is not empty use just the list name `self.ircnicklist` instead of `len(self.ircnicklist) != 0`
- Review exception types. Is `IndexError` really appropriate when there are no more elements in the list?l
- Prefer to use list comprehensions instead of `map`
- Remove `pass` if isn't really useful. Instead of:

  ```
  if not self.nickpassword:
      pass
  else:
      self.sock.send("PASS %s\r\n" % self.nickpassword)
  ```

  write:

  ```
  if self.nickpassword:
      self.sock.send("PASS %s\r\n" % self.nickpassword)
  ```
- Instead of `while 1` use `while True`
- Use context managers to open and close files. Instead of:

  ```
  f = open(filename, 'a+')
  f.write("<%s>%s\n" % (ircclientinstance.getusernick(
      serverbuffer), ircclientinstance.getusermessage(serverbuffer)))
  f.close()
  ```

  write:

  ```
  with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
      f.write("<%s>%s\n"
              % (ircclientinstance.getusernick(serverbuffer),
                 ircclientinstance.getusermessage(serverbuffer)))
  ```

I hope this helps.